# INPUT TYPE=FILE does not work in Microsoft edge

Tags: html, browser, microsoft-edge

I am trying to upload file (`.doc`/`docx`) from Microsoft edge (`Version 25.10586.0.0`). I am unable to upload any file (`.doc`/`.docx`) which is open. It also does not provide any error message. However, I am able to upload any open document in `IE11`/`Chrome Version 47.0.2526.111 m`/`Firefox 43.0.4`.

```
<form >
  Select a file: <input type="file">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Can anyone please help me to fix this issue?

Comment: Only files that are currently opened? And in the other Browsers it works with the same currently opened files?

Comment: @CodeiSir exactly ....

Comment: It will be helpful for me if the down-voter add any comment.

Answer (score 12):

I work on the Microsoft Edge team, and can confirm the issue you're reporting. I'll need to do a little more digging to understand the full scope of this. Cursory investigation showed that Excel and Word both prevented me from uploading a file, while PowerPoint did not. I also was *unable* to reproduce the issue with other media types, such as images.

I'm going to file a bug for the team to investigate the matter further. I'll report back when the issue has been resolved. Thank you for the neat discovery.

Comment: Thank you for your reply :).

Comment: @Sampson Any news on this ?

Comment: Can still recreate the Word and Excel issue pointed out here using Edge 25.105686.0.0 (as of 2nd August 2016).

Comment: @JamieTaylor I wouldn't expect a servicing fix for this; the change would more likely take place in a future update of Microsoft Edge. I'm not sure if this has been resolved yet, but Edge 38 ships today with many other improvements. I'll look into this when I'm back at the office.

Comment: @Sampson... Just hit browser testing and Edge is the only browser that seems not to respond to the change event for excel files.  Works fine with CSV/text.

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue, which embarrassed me in front of client.:P

Comment: I am no longer on the Edge team (or at Microsoft, for that matter) but I believe this issue can be avoided by simply closing the file before you attempt to upload. @AmitKumar

Comment: @KiwiSunGoddess See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34850628/input-type-file-does-not-work-in-microsoft-edge/34889646?noredirect=1#comment69135158_34889646

Comment: Thanks @Sampson, this solution was unacceptable to my Dev manager.  Fortunately he spent some time working on it and also gave up :).  Best workaround I offered was notifying the client if using edge that the file had to be closed.  Certainly looks like Microsoft aren't worrying too much about this bug